# Merge [tag:hacking] into [tag:security]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[hacking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/hacking) isn't substantively different from [security](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/security) in context, and it should be made a synonym.  Shall it be done?

Comment: Question counts: "361 questions tagged [hacking]", "230 questions tagged [hacking] not [security]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not convinced this should be done. Security is quite a broad topic, and "hacking" is clearly only a narrow subset.

This will also potentially inconvenience the 30 people who are following this tag, and may not want to see all questions from the broader tag.

What do we gain from merging these tags?

Comment: They're not distinguishable at all.  I can't think of any question that could be tagged with one but not the other.

Comment: So, if they aren't distinguishable, then it would be fine to go the other direction: rename security to hacking? Somehow I don't think this is true.

Answer (score -5):

Merge away.

[image]